# Monoids and Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

The Question:
Determine all groups G such that $ \{ H=(g,g^2): g \in G \}$  is a subgroup of $ G\times G$

I am confused what the question is asking for. I assume there is some small finite number of groups that satisfy this property i.e groups with 4 or less elements.

Things I know:

- The subgroup test states that if H is a subgroup then it must contain the identity element of G(say $e$) but since $e^2=e$ then by the criterion of H every cartesian product $G \times G$ contains $(e,e^2)$ Right?
- If $(g,g^2)$,$(h,h^2)$ $\in$ H then $(gh,(gh)^2)$ $\in$ H. Not sure how to proceed with this. And if $(g,g^2)$ $\in$ H then $(g^{-1},(g^2)^{-1})$ $\in$ H.

Any hints/clarifications would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about the identity.

Since $g^{-2} = (g^{-1})^2$, we're good for inverses.

If we multiply $(g,g^2)$ with $(h,h^2)$ we get $(gh,g^2h^2)$ which isn't of the form $(gh)^2$ unless $g^2h^2=ghgh$.  Multiplying on the left by $g^{-1}$ and on the right by $h^{-1}$ gives $gh=hg$.  So only commutative (aka Abelian) groups will work, but we're done with properties, so *any* commutative group will work.